# How to remove x-powered-by header in nextjs custom server

Tags: node.js, express, next.js

I'm using Next to create a web app, and I want to remove `x-powered-by` from response header, I tried to create custom server and use expressjs `.disable('x-powered-by')` but it didn't work.

here is what I've done:

```
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3001
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()


app.prepare()
.then(() => {
  const server = express()
  .use(handle)


  server.disable('x-powered-by'); // ???

  server.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
  })
})
```

Comment: why? don't you want to return the response with this header? or in the whole request?

Comment: @BasilBattikhi I want to hide `nextjs` version in my app, currently `X-Powered-By:Next.js 4.2.1` header returns in all requests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code works. What you are doing here is correct to remove X-Powered-By header from Express. Because you are using Next you need to disable **both Next and Express** X-Powered-By header.

I did not find api from Next to disable. But you can directly change the object `app.config.poweredByHeader = false`

```
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3001
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.config.poweredByHeader = false

app.prepare()
.then(() => {
  const server = express().use(handle)

  server.disable('x-powered-by'); // This disables Express Header

  server.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
  })
})
```

Comment: another way would be `app.set('x-powered-by', false)`.

Answer (score 7):

For me when I use `server.disable('x-powered-by');`, was ended up with `Next.js 7.0.2` as `x-powered-by` value.

adding below line in `next.config.js` should work

```
module.exports = {
    poweredByHeader: false,
    ...
}
```

or

```
const app = next({ dev, xPoweredBy: false })
```

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple now.

By default Next.js will add the x-powered-by header. To opt-out of it, open next.config.js and disable the poweredByHeader config:

```
module.exports = {
  poweredByHeader: false,
}
```

See - https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/disabling-x-powered-by

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you dont want to return this header you have to simply write

```
res.removeHeader('header-name'); //any header that you want to remove
```

So you need to write

```
res.removeHeader('X-Powered-By');
```

in the End Point

Comment: This isn't work, if I was using express and define my own routes you were right, and I could remove header using `removeHeader`, but this isn't work when I use `app.getRequestHandler()` to handle requests